# Parse wordpress blog data using json api and ajax

Tags: jquery, javascript, json

I have seen lots of responses to how to extract data from wordpress blog posts using the json api plugin. Many uses $.getJSON, $.ajax, .responseData.feed.entries, success function() etc.

What is the correct way to parse JSON API datas from wordpress, post the result to a content div page in a jQuery mobile listview.

I have the following codes but unable to get the intended result:

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
    Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <script src="css/style.css"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="blog" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" class="sys_hd" data-position="fixed" data-id="sys_header" >
        <h1>Sysads Posts</h1>
        </div><!-- header -->
        <div data-theme="c" data-role="content" id="postlist"> </div><!-- content -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="sys_footer" >
                    <div data-role="navbar" >
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#blog" class="sys_ft">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#blog" class="sys_ft">Disclaimer</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- navbar --> 
        </div><!-- footer --> 
    </div><!-- page -->
</body>
</html>
```

.js:

```
$( document).ready(function (){
    url = 'http://hopexxx.com/category/daily-devotion/feed/' ;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(){
            alert( 'Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed' );
        },
        success: function(data ){
            var postlist = data.responseData.feed.entries;
            var html = '<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">' ;
            for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
                var entry = postlist[i];
                html += '<li>';
                html += '<a href="#">';
                html += '<div class="entry">' + entry.title + '</div>' ;
                html += '<div class="entry">' + entry.author + '</div>' ;
                html += '<div class="entry">' + entry.publishedDate + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="entry">' + entry.contentSnippet + '</div>';
                html += '</a>';
                html += '</li>';
            }
            html += '</ul>';
            $( "#postlist" ).append(html);
           $( "#postlist ul[data-role=listview]" ).listview();

        }});
    });
```

I hope my question is not outside the site rule.

Comment: I have added the js code. It displays the lists. I need it to display just the posts when I click on each link and also for it to append more posts when a link at the buttom is clicked

Comment: Anyone able to help

Answer (score 1):

Got this working: Added html += '';

```
html += '<li>';
html += '<a href="' + entry.link + '">';
html += '<div class="entry">' + entry.title + '</div>' ;
html += '<div class="entry">' + entry.author + '</div>' ;
html += '<div class="entry">' + entry.publishedDate + '</div>';
html += '<div class="entry">' + entry.contentSnippet + '</div>';
html += '</a>';
html += '</li>';
```

Comment: Next is to display each post in its own formatted page rather than the link calling the main website with all the widgets

Comment: If you answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer.